# ValueError: invalid literal for int() error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Hi I am using Django framework for my website. I've a View in project which saves data in to the database (Models). But when I run my program am getting an error as follows

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2015-08-24 12:27:58'`

My views.py

```
class ProcessCheckBinningView(JSONResponseMixin, View):
    #model = OrcAwaiverBin
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        status = 'error'
        msg = "this is from me"

        post_body = json.loads(self.request.body)
        fab_value = post_body['fab']
        technode_value = post_body['technode']
        layer_value = post_body['layer']

        print fab_value, technode_value, layer_value
        print "submitted from the template f"
        bin_object = OrcAwaiverBin()
        # Record the last accessed date
        bin_object.fab = fab_value
        bin_object.technology = technode_value
        bin_object.layer = layer_value
        print "OKKKKK"
        bin_object.created_by = '2015-08-24 12:27:58'
        bin_object.date_modified = '2015-08-24 12:27:58'
        bin_object.save()
        return self.render_json_response(dict(status=status, msg=msg))

class CheckBinningView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "orc_enable.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(CheckBinningView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        fab = GroupProfile.objects.get(id=self.request.session['ACL_gid']).fab
        gp = GroupProfile.objects.get(id=self.request.session['ACL_gid'])
        context['fab'] = gp.fab
        context['ngapp'] = "CMOD"
        return context
```

My Model fields:

```
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
date_modified = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
```

Can someone tell me whats the problem here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paste the code for  models.py for the `OrcAwaiverBin` Model

Comment: Updated with my model fields

Comment: @gentle Please post full stack trace! Besides, are you sure `self.request.session['ACL_gid']` is integer, as you are trying to get `GroupProfile` object by `id`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what the error suggests, You should have declared the `bin_object.created_by` field or `bin_object.date_modified` field as `IntegerField`.

Comment: No its Datetime field. Updated my question with models also

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, as Aswin said my model only accept integer values. I was trying to insert datetime value. Thanks folks!